# can postgres logs be accessed through pg_stats_activity table

Tags: postgresql

I am logging postgres queries in a log file, because I want to track which user executed how many queries.

Is there any possibility to access these logs via SQL through tables?

Please give your suggestion. I want to track the users usage of Postgres SQL queries.

I want to know how many queries are executed by the user in a table or view.

Comment: you can use `file_fdw`. The manual even has an example on how to do that: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/file-fdw.html#id-1.11.7.23.14

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: should make a short and useful answer ...

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name : Hi thanks for your answer.i have one more doubt.i have created the fdw with OPTIONS ( filename '/home/josh/data/log/pglog.csv', format 'csv' ) But my log file are generating with date appended in the filename.The filename is here dynamic and names change daily.In this situation how should i specify the OPTIONS.i want the daily log files are appended into the table and i would like to log only the queries executed by the user.please give your suggestion. –